# How to Adjust the Kerning Between the Letters in a Title (Is It Possible with PdfLatex?)

Tags: spacing, xetex, pdftex, titles, kerning

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{pgothic}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vskip 35pt
\begin{center}
\begin{Huge}
\begin{pgothfamily}
{\vstretch{1.45}{\textbf{\scalefont{1.15}{Would Like to Adju{s}t the Spacing}}}} \vspace*{10pt} {\vstretch{1.45}{\textbf{\scalefont{1.15}{Between the Letters}}}}
\end{pgothfamily}
\end{Huge}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the title

[image]

QUESTION: How may I adjust (increase in this case) the spacing between the letters in such a title? Is it possible using Pdflatex? If so, how? If not, how may this be done with Xelatex?

Thank you.

Comment: soul package or more generally see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letterspacing

Comment: beware using `\end{Huge}`  as an enviornment wihout including end of paragraph, you will get huge text on a normal baseline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different approach...a token cycle.  Here, each character is individually scaled (using `\scalebox{1.15}[1.6675]{...}`) and set bold, followed by a kern of `\mygap`.  Likewise, each space is augmented by a `2\mygap` kern and allowed to break a line.

This aproach will preclude hyphenation, but in a title, that may be preferred.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{tokcycle,graphicx}
\def\mygap{3pt}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{\scalebox{1.15}[1.6675]{\bfseries#1}\kern
  \mygap}}
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{#1\kern\mygap\kern\mygap\allowbreak}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vskip 35pt
\begin{center}
\begingroup\Huge
\begin{pgothfamily}
\tokencyclexpress
Would Like to Adju{s}t the Spacing Between the Letters
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{pgothfamily}
\endgroup
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer. However, when I run it both with pdflatex and xelatex, I get the following error: `line 6: "tokcycle,sty" not found'. Could this be something I do not have? Is it possible to modify the code without it? Thanks again.

Comment: I must be missing the package `tokcycle`. Hopefully I will be able to load it on one of my computers. Thank you again.

Comment: @mlchristians See https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle.  The two needed files for the package are tokcycle.tex and tokcycle.sty.  In addition, you will find documentation and examples.

Comment: Thanks again @Steven B. Segletes.